# Why dialog fragment dissmiss and lose data onconfiguration change

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have dialog fragment containes list of users so When my dialog fragment is showing and I change let's say the language or activate or disactivate dark mode or any other config change my dialog fragment dissmiss and lose state

so this how i create the dialog :

```
 CheckableContactsDialog.newInstance(object : CheckableContactListener {
                override fun onPositiveClick(selected: MutableList<String>) {
                     checkableContactsDialog?.dismiss()
                    if (mVCall != null) {
                        val (phones, phoneFlat) = extractPhonesNumberFromContacts(
                            context, selected
                        )
                        if (phones.isEmpty()) {
                            return
                        }
                        inviteNewUsers(phoneFlat)
                    }
                }

                override fun onNegativeClick() {
                    checkableContactsDialog?.dismiss()

                }
            })
```

After configchange like language change or activate or desactivate dark mode and trigger the  onPositiveClick event and checkableContactsDialog?.dismiss() called this error appear

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.zetabox.totrapp, PID: 4368
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CheckableContactsDialog{58e7d9c} (77fb6c1e-6986-4eb0-8e35-c1ee51f4e0c9) not associated with a fragment manager.
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getParentFragmentManager(Fragment.java:1040)
at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:350)
at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:307)
at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment.dismiss(BottomSheetDialogFragment.java:47)
at com.zetabox.totrapp.ui.call.CallActivity$showAddUserDialog$1.onPositiveClick(CallActivity.kt:2123)
at com.zetabox.totrapp.ui.dialogs.CheckableContactsDialog.init$lambda-7(CheckableContactsDialog.kt:231)
at com.zetabox.totrapp.ui.dialogs.CheckableContactsDialog.$r8$lambda$BXYvl1NNrhMJYwo5PbYyZJ1LQtM(Unknown Source:0)
at com.zetabox.totrapp.ui.dialogs.CheckableContactsDialog$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7171)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7148)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:802)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27409)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7650)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: Did you use `ViewModel` to hold your data?

Comment: yes but the problem as shown on the exception the fragment manager has been lost when activity recreated  and when i  try to dissmiss